# Install cocoapods for flutter on mac failed

Tags: macos, flutter, cocoapods

I try to install cocoapods version 1.10.1 on Catalina (10.15.7) to use with flutter because flutter will not run with newest version. But building it failed and I can't figure out why. Looks like some dev libraries are missing but I can't find what is going on.

I try brew but that was not a success:
`brew install cocoapods@1.10.1`

Any help is appreciated.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.1
Fetching cocoapods-try-1.2.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-downloader-1.5.1.gem
Fetching cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-search-1.0.1.gem
Fetching cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5.gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-try-1.2.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-search-1.0.1
Successfully installed cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-1.5.1
Successfully installed cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210929-40930-1xenmbu.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in `try_ldflags'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.4/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
flutter clean
project root dir>> cd ios
pod install
pod update
```

it will solve your problem if you are still facing the same issue do let me know.
if its help you please thumbs up my answer.

Comment: Same problem with flutter 


```
 pod install
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
        11: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

ps: LANG="en_US.UTF-8" is already in ~/.profile

```
locaLe
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```